# How to prepare my training set for training if the ROI is not squared?

Tags: neural-networks, dataset, conv-neural-network

I'm a beginner in CNN and I'm trying to create my own Network, but I have a question in case you've been through this.

Imagine we have thousands of pictures of human heads (hair, face and neck) and you're only interested in classifying them with a ROI (Region Of Interest) of their forehead and cheeks. Obviously the ROI is not squared at all.

I'm interested in passing the input in RGB (density 3) since I'm interested in colours too.

Imagine you have the ROI already in a separate mask, how would you train the network?

My options are:
- First segment the image, get a squared image from the ROI and set to black (0) the rest (basically, apply a mask to the image and let visible the interesting part).
- Pass the mask parameter as another value of the input (RGBA, where A is the Alpha value of the MASK, might be 0 or 1). This would pass the entire image AND the mask.

What do you think?

Visual example:

**Image**

[image]

**Mask (ROI)**

[image]

**Image with mask**

[image]

Comment: Whats an roi? You did not define that abbreviation. Please edit into your post.